# Is there a way to connect PBI to a Databricks cluster that is not running?

Tags: powerbi, databricks

In my scenario, Databricks is performing read and writing transformations in Delta tables. We have PBI connected to the Databricks cluster that needs to be running most of the time, which is expensive.

Knowing that delta tables are in a container, what would be the best way in terms of cost x performance to feed PBI from delta tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your set size is under max allowed size in PowerBI (100 GB I guess) and daily refresh is enough you can just load everything to your PowerBI model.

https://blog.gbrueckl.at/2021/01/reading-delta-lake-tables-natively-in-powerbi/

If you want to save the costs maybe you don't need transactions and can save it in csv in data lake, than loading everything to PowerBI and refresh daily is really easy.

If you want to save the costs and query new incoming data all the time  using DirectQuery consider using Azure SQL. It has really competitive prices starting from 5 eur/usd. Integration with databricks is also perfect write in append mode do all magic.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to consider is to create an Azure Synapse workspace and [use serverless SQL compute to query the delta lake files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-delta-lake-format?). This is a pay-per-the-TB consumed pricing model so you don’t have to have your Databricks cluster running all the time. It’s a great way to load Power BI import models.